# PChar Invalid Pointer Operation on StrPLCopy

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I write some TCP-server usin WinSock 2 and I hava procedure which catch FD_READ event. In this procedure I need to parse recieved message. The code is here:

```
procedure TfrmMain.WndProc_OnWSANetEvent(var Msg: TMessage);
Var
  iCurrThread, n : Integer;
  i : Integer;
  temp : PChar;
  len : Integer;
  params : PChar;
  username : PChar; password : PChar;
  ind : Integer;
  tempy : PChar;
  tempn : PChar;
begin
  case WSAGetSelectEvent(Msg.LParam) of
    FD_READ :
      while True do
      begin
        if (FreeRThreads.GetCount <> 0) then
          begin
            iCurrThread := FreeRThreads.Pop;
            if (ReadThreads[iCurrThread].Terminated) then
              begin
                ReadThreads[iCurrThread].SetFSocket(Msg.WParam);
                ReadThreads[iCurrThread].Execute;

                temp := ReadThreads[iCurrThread].GetFText;
                meLog.Lines.Add(temp);

                if (copy(temp,1,2)='AU') then
                  begin
                    StrPLCopy(params, PChar(copy(temp, 7, StrToInt( copy(temp, 3, 4) ) )), 16372);
                    ind := pos(' ', params);
                    StrPLCopy(username, PChar(copy(params, 1, ind-1)), 16372);
                    StrPLCopy(password, PChar(copy(params, ind + 1, StrLen(params))), 16372);

                    StrPLCopy(tempy, PChar('AU0001y'), 14);
                    StrPLCopy(tempn, PChar('AU0001n'), 14);

                    if (username=PChar('dizpers')) then
                      if (password=PChar('admin')) then
                        send(Msg.WParam, tempy^, 14, 0)
                      else
                        send(Msg.WParam, tempn^, 14, 0)
                    else
                      send(Msg.WParam, tempn^, 14, 0);

                    meLog.Lines.Add('USER = '+username);
                    meLog.Lines.Add('PASSWORD = '+password);
                  end;



                FreeRThreads.Push(iCurrThread);
                break;
              end;
          end;
      end;
    FD_CLOSE :
      begin
        n := CSocketsCount - 1;
        for i := 0 to n do
          if (ClientSockets[i] = Msg.WParam) then
            begin
              closesocket(ClientSockets[i]);
              FreeSockets.Push(i);
              break;
            end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

While debugging I have an "Acces Violation ... write of address ..." on the line

```
StrPLCopy(params, PChar(copy(temp, 7, StrToInt( copy(temp, 3, 4) ) )), 16372);
```

Plz, help me to solve this problem and understand why it's happened. TIA!

Comment: Any reason why you didn't go with a TCP component set like Indy (or others)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must allocate memory for the `params` variable before to use [`StrPLCopy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrPLCopy) (the same goes for `username`,`password`,`tempy`,`tempn`)

check this sample

```
Var
  Dest   : PChar;
  Source : PChar;
begin
    Source:='This is a buffer to copy';
    //alloc a buffer of 1024 bytes 
    GetMem(Dest,1024);
    try
      //copy 
      StrPLCopy(Dest, Source, Length(Source));
      //do something
      Writeln(Dest);
    finally
      //free the memory
      FreeMem(Dest);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thx! The sample works fine. But now I have another question. I know size of memory, which I need to allocate, but about other PChar variables I know only that their length should be at most 16372. So, who can I get memory for variable if I don't know size?

Comment: @dizpers please ask that as a new question, with some more details

Comment: Declare the variable as `array[0..16371] of Char` which also eliminates the explicit memory allocation.